# Android: EditText cannot cope with amout of text?

Tags: android, android-edittext, widget, richtext

Does anyone know how it would be possible to load very long text with rich formatting into an EditText without it crashing? Yesterday I tested an app I am working on, and loaded a 600 line XML document which was then syntax highlighted into the EditText. That worked fine, but as I was scrolling, the EditText could not cope with the amout of rich text it was rendering, and I recieved an ANR. Any suggestions?